# Interpretation of the basis and coordinates for this solution space.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I found $x_1=x_3$ and $x_2=0$. So, $x_1=t;x_2=0; x_3=t$

Therefore: $$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=t(1,0,1)$$

So, the dimension is $1$ and the basis is $(1,0,1)$.

Now, I am having trouble interpreting this because this means that the coordinate vector relative to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is $(t)$.  I understand that this has dimension $1$ but how can there just be a $1$ component coordinate if there are 3 components making up this vector?

$${(x_1,x_2,x_3)}_{(1,0,1)}=(t)$$

Comment: the coordinates are (t,0,t), but as we have (t,0,t)=t(1,0,1) we have a single parameter t.  Letting the parameter t vary we get all possible coordinates (t,0,t) on the line.

Comment: Does this mean that the coordinates of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ relative to $(1,0,1)$ is a point $t$ in 1 dimensional space?

Comment: Yes that's a way to think of it.  You have a real line (1-dimensional) floating in three space, in the direction of (1,0,1).  Think of t then as just a number on that real line, just like the regular number line.  The number 8 is taking t=8 in the direction (1,0,0) if the x-axis is the standard number line.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know,  the dimension of the space spanned by $(1,0,1)$ is $1$. What this means is that any vector in this space is a scalar multiple of $(1,0,1)$. For example, $(5,0,5)$ is in this space , since it equal to $5(1,0,1)$. This $5$ at the beginning is unique for the vector we have chosen and it is called the coordinate.

Comment: $5$ is the coordinate vector relative to $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$.  So, how can there be a vector with $1$ component relative to a vector with $3$ components?

Comment: ${(x_1,x_2,x_3)}_{(1,0,1)}=(t)$

Comment: The coordinate vectors are different from the other vectors in the space. The coordinates consist of elements of the field over which the space is defined, while the other vectors are elements of the space.

Comment: ${(x_1,x_2,x_3)}_{(1,0,1)}=(t)$ This reads as: the coordinate vector of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ relative to $(1,0,1$ is $(t)$. No?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think the confusing is arising because of the notation used.

Comment: How can the coordinate vector relative to a vector with 3 components be $(t)$, which is one component?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13887/discussion-between-panda-bear-and-lanfranco)

Comment: I am not able to log in. Sorry and this might be of help http://www.math4all.in/public_html/linear%20algebra/chapter5.3.html

Comment: Does this mean that the coordinates of $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ relative to $(1,0,1)$ is a point $t$ in 1 dimensional space?

Comment: Sorry, can't continue the discussion. Really sorry!